# Docker-compose: show containers usage of resources

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to see resource usage by docker containers?

I am using docker-compose version 2.1 and 2.4.
I would like to see running containers and their resources usage: RAM, CPU.
`docker-compose ps` returns containers, images, but not resources.

```
$ docker-compose ps
             Name                           Command                  State                                  Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
service-1                        /app.sh                         Up (healthy)     8001/tcp
service-2                        /app.sh                         Up (healthy)     0.0.0.0:80->4000/tcp
kafka                            /etc/confluent/docker/run       Up               0.0.0.0:29092->29092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7071->7071/tcp, 9092/tcp
mongo                            /init.sh                        Up (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
zookeeper                        /etc/confluent/docker/run       Up               2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32181->32181/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see container resource usages with `docker stats` command.

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                             CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
95f5cdca9700        service-1                        0.01%               35.39MiB / 381.5MiB   9.28%               141kB / 78kB        19.7MB / 0B         3
df49fdac6009        service-2                        10.43%              278.6MiB / 381.5MiB   73.02%              126MB / 183MB       435MB / 0B          151
9dff501eb008        kafka                            12.62%              348.1MiB / 572.2MiB   60.83%              610MB / 188MB       223MB / 0B          224
c00000a1d397        zookeeper                        21.27%              313.7MiB / 381.5MiB   82.23%              600MB / 220MB       209MB / 0B          281
6d2d5000bb2e        mongo                            14.56%              325.8MiB / 381.5MiB   85.39%              531MB / 211MB       259MB / 0B          245
```